# Find the ratio of the areas of $3$ regions when a circle touches one side of a rectangle and passes through the opposite $2$ vertices.

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

> **QUESTION:** A rectangle $OACB$ with its two axes as it's two sides, the origin $O$ as a vertex is drawn in which the length $OA$ is four times the length $OB$. A circle is drawn passing through the points $B$ and $C$ and touching $OA$ at it's mid-point, thus dividing the rectangle into $3$ parts. Find the ratio of the areas of these $3$ parts.

**MY ANSWER:** Without loss of generality, I assume $B$ to be $(0,1)$  and therefore $A$ is $(4,0)$, $M$ is $(2,0)$, $C$ is $(4,1)$. Now the circle passes through $B$, $C$, $M$. I assume the equation of the circle to be $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$. Therefore we have $3$ variables namely $a$, $b$, $r$ and three equations (from the three points).. and therefore, we can solve it. Upon calculation I have found out the following values $→$
$a=2$, $b=\frac{5}2$, $r=\frac{5}2$.

Therefore, the equation of the circle can be written as $y=\sqrt{{(\frac{5}2)^2-(x-2)^2}} + \frac{5}2$

Therefore, the area of one part is simply$→$

$\int_{0}^{2}ydx$

or,

$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{{(\frac{5}2)^2-(x-2)^2}}+\frac{5}2$

Which upon calculation comes out to be $\frac{13}2-\frac{25}8sin^{-1}(\frac{-4}5)$.

Now this gives the area of the region excluding the circle (I tried to attach an image, but it didn't upload :( ). Obviously, the two parts leaving what is inside the circular region are symmetrical and therefore have the same area as found above.

Now the area of the circular region is just $4-$ the area found by integration (since, $4$ is the area of the rectangle). So we get all the required areas like this.

Now my question is, how can I calculate such a dangerous ratio!?.. I mean there is an inverse of sin which cannot be done manually, and I cannot reduce the terms to any satisfactory extent.. is my answer wrong? If not, how do I simplify this one?

One more question, is there a simpler way to make this sum done? It will be very helpful if you can tell me that too.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The geometric solution below may be simpler.

Note the part above the circle line is a circular cap with an angle span of $2\alpha = 2\sin^{-1}\frac45$. Its area can be obtained as the difference between those of the corresponding circle sector and the overlapping triangle, i.e.

$$ A_1= \frac12(2\alpha)r^2 -\frac12 4 (r-1)= \frac{25}4\sin^{-1}\frac45 - 3
$$

and the area of the two equal corner parts is

$$A_2=A_3=\frac12(4-A_1) = \frac72- \frac{25}8\sin^{-1}\frac45 $$

Thus, their ratio is

$$A_1:A_2:A_3= \frac{50\alpha-24}{28-25\alpha}:1:1,\>\>\>\alpha =\sin^{-1}\frac45$$

You made a mistake in integrating the area. It should be

$$\int_{0}^{2}\left(\frac52-\sqrt{{\frac{25}4-(x-2)^2}}\right)dx 
= \frac72- \frac{25}8\sin^{-1}\frac45 
$$

Comment: According to the equation of the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$, we get, $y=\sqrt{r^2-(x-a)^2} +b$. Then where is the mistake that I made?.. According to your solution, the integration should be $b-\sqrt{r^2-(x-a)^2}$, how did you do that?...

Comment: One more query, can you please provide a figure for your geometric solution?.. I didn't understand how you got the area of $A_1$..

Comment: @StrangerForever - There are two equations $\frac52\pm \sqrt{{\frac{25}4-(x-2)^2}}$ for the integrand. The lower part of the circle is given by the negative square root.

Comment: @StrangerForever - I’ll add a diagram to illustrate the geometry

Comment: Thank you so much.. waiting eagerly for it..

Comment: Oh this is what I missed.. I didn't consider the $±$ when I did my calculation.. thanks a ton..!

Comment: @StrangerForever - see the diagram

Comment: Thank you so much